# How can i test my json in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to test my method Account.find whether it returns me the right result or not. I get the below error.

```
  it "can find an account " do 
    Account.find(id: @acc.id, authorization: @token);         
    expect(response.status).to have_http_status(200);
    body = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(body["name"]).to eq "Test"    
  end
```

> NameError: undefined local variable or method response.

How can i check for the right `response` and `response code`.

Comment: paste the Account class

Comment: @jvnill: I have updated the Account class.

Comment: when you test Controller, response will be available to you. it is undefined in Model test.

Comment: @Saravanan: Can you show that to me.

Comment: account = Account.find(id: @acc.id, authorization: @token);
account.name.should == "test"

Comment: I get undefined method name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work as what you want to actually test is the request answer. Try:

```
  it "can find an account that this user belongs to" do 
    get "/accounts/#{@acc.id}/", headers # like the token or whatever your api needs

    expect(response).to be_success 

    # now you have the response.body available to do:
    body = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(body["name"]).to eq "Test"  

  end
```